# Will IPv6 addresses work in IPv4 mode?

Tags: iphone, networking, bind, ipv6, bsd

I'm working on migrating some code from IPv4 only to IPv6, and of course I need to retain backwards compatibility for IPv4.

I have read through some documents and guides for converting my code, and have seen it written that using many of the newer APIs (like inet_pton() instead of inet_addr()) will just work in both IPv4 and IPv6.

However, in some cases it still isn't clear when I need to write code to handle each protocol in a different way. Specifically, I don't know whether a IPv6 address (family AF_INET6 using sockaddr_storage structure) will work on a local network.

So for example, let's say I create such an address using the built in constant in6addr_loopback, and then I try to use that for a parameter to a bind() call.

Will this work in both IPv4 and IPv6, or I need to create the right address type (AF_INET vs AF_INET6) for each case? Does it matter whether I am connecting to a local socket (i.e. the loopback as in this case) as opposed to a socket on an external device?

My client code is running on iPhone/iPad hardware in case it matters.

Answer (score 2):

Every interface will derive a link local ipv6 address using mac address. This address is sufficient for communication within local network.
Regarding creation of socket, you need to specify the family (AF_INET and AF_INET6) and initialize and bind it.

IPv4:

```
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
```

IPv6:

```
     struct sockaddr_in6 serv_addr, cli_addr;
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     serv_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
     serv_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
     serv_addr.sin6_port = htons(portno);

     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: I know how to create both socket types, but my question is that I always create a IPv6 type for all scenarios. Will that work for all network types, including a IPv4-only network?

Comment: Nope, you would need to support both protocols, unless your ipv6 host does ipv4 tunneling for ipv4 connections.

Comment: But how do I know which protocol to use? To keep things simple, let's say I am only doing connections to a localhost server.

Comment: I don't understand your above question.
Theoretically:
1) There will be a IPv6 server thread which binds on IPv6 address and accepts all IPv6 client connections.
2) Similarly there will be another server thread which binds on IPv4 address and accepts all IPv4 client connections.

Is this something you wanted to know? Can you please elaborate what is the implementation challenge you are facing.